# Не работает geoip в PHP

Tags: geoip, php

Всем привет.
Поставил с помощью pecl - geoip, пытаюсь с помощью функции `geoip_record_by_name()` получить город, а выводит NULL.
Нашёл, что при выводе всех баз данных, подключённых (`geoip_db_get_all_info()`), стоит значение  `["available"]=> bool(false)`, адрес правильный к бд, база тоже лежит там. А вот значение `false`, где это поменять? Не нашёл в Интернете, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неправильно указывал путь, всё оказалось проще, чем могло быть.